# Aurelia: @autoinject does not inject Element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, aurelia

I have some strange bevaviour with the `@autoinject()` decorator in my custom attribute.

The constructor of the attribute looks like this:

```
constructor(element: Element,translationService: TranslationService, eventAggregator: EventAggregator){
    console.log(element);
    console.log(translationService);
    console.log(eventAggregator);
    ...
}
```

The class is decorated with `@autionject()`, while the parameters `translationService` and `eventAggregator` are injected correctly the `element` parameter is filled with an object with is definitively not an element.

The element looks like this:

```
{
    jQuery321051167339178565241 : {events: {…}, handle: ƒ}
    __proto__: Object
}
```

When I use `@inject(Element, TranslationService, EventAggregator)` instead of `@autoinject()` the element is injected correctly.

Does somebody have a guess what's going wrong?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/97

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is a jquery wrapped element (e.g. what you get if you call `$(el)`), so possibly TypeScript is somehow emitting the wrong type metadata.

To be able to fix this, you'll need to include your typescript version, tsconfig, build configuration and Aurelia version.

In the meantime, look at the emitted `.js` of your app when you use `@autoinject()` and search for "design:paramTypes" which is tied to your custom attribute. It should look something like this:

```
exports.MyCustomAttribute = __decorate([
    aureliaDependencyInjection.autoinject(),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [Element])
], exports.MyCustomAttribute);
```

Then switch to `@inject(Element)`, build and do the same thing. You should find something like this:

```
exports.MyCustomAttribute = __decorate([
    aureliaDependencyInjection.inject(Element),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [Element])
], exports.MyCustomAttribute);
```

See if the `Element` object passed to `aureliaDependencyInjection.inject(..)` is different from the one passed to `__metadata("design:paramtypes", ..)`

That should help rule out whether TypeScript is indeed emitting the wrong metadata, or if something else is going wrong.